# Writing IF, ELSEIF ELSE

Tags: json, vba, if-statement

Im trying to write a VBA If statement.
I am checking to see if certain JSON nodes exist.

There are three types, the First Node, Continuation Node, and a malformed empty node.

It keeps getting hung up on the first one, when it is.

```
If Not jSonRoot.child("MediaType").child("first") Is Nothing Then  
    'First Pass  
ElseIf Not jSonRoot.child("second") Is Nothing Then  
    'Continuation  
Else  
    'Json is nothing, malformed.  
End If
```

Comment: "hung up" how? And are you guaranteed that there will be a `MediaType` child of `jSonRoot` in **all cases**? (Because the code is relying on that premise by calling `.child` on the result of `.child("MediaType")`.)

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to guess that sometimes, there is no `MediaType` child; in which case, the first `If` will blow up because you're trying to call `.child("first")` on `Nothing`.

If I'm right, sadly, you have to separate that first condition out into separate `If` statements because VBA doesn't have short-circuiting for `And`:

```
If Not jSonRoot.child("MediaType") Is Nothing Then  
    If Not jSonRoot.child("MediaType").child("first") Is Nothing Then  
        'First Pass  
    Else
        'Handle case where there's a MediaType but no .child("first")
    End If
ElseIf Not jSonRoot.child("second") Is Nothing Then  
    'Continuation  
Else  
    'Json is nothing, malformed.  
End If
```